# Extract a vector from a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

For a square matrix Z,
I know that Z=z*z'
Is there an already defined function in Matlab that enables me to extract z from Z? (note that z is a vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Divakar's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709098/1714410) is very simple and elegant, but has a few drawbacks:

1. It is able to reconstruct elements of `z` up to sign, that is, you'll have to check with `Z(ii,jj)` what exactly are the **signs** of `z(ii)` and `z(jj)`.
2. In case of noise, that is `Z = z*z' + noise` the reconstruction may be way off...

Therefore, one might want to use a slightly more robust method, using [singular value decomposition (SVD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition):

```
[U S V] = svd( Z );
z = U(:,1) * sqrt(S(1,1));
```

This will give you the optimal rank-one in L2 sense: that is a rank one matrix that is closest to `Z` in L2 norm.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have mentioned `Z=z*z'`, you are assuming `z` as a column vector.

Now, if you manually perform the multiplication assuming some values in the column vector `z` and then if you perform `Z=z*z'`, you would notice that the diagonal elements are squares of the vector elements.

You can use this property to retrieve back `z` from `Z`, by first getting the diagonal elements of `Z` with `diag` and then performing square root on those with `sqrt`. The code below does all that -

```
z = sqrt(diag(Z))
```

Comment: would that make sense if I already know that diag(Z) is all ones?

Comment: @AmiraAkra Then your `z` has to be all ones too. Actually they could be all negative ones too, because square of both `-x` or `+x` result in x^2.